# Instantiate multiple objects in a non-mutable array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I often find myself implementing methods that create a bunch of objects in a loop and return them in a non-mutable array. 
I'd usually write something like this:

```
- (NSArray *)myObjects {
    NSMutableArray *_temporaryArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id foo in foos) {
        // ... 
        // create `myObject` from the information in `foo`
        // ... 
        [_temporaryArray addObject:myObject];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:_temporaryArray];
}
```

Somehow this pattern doesn't feel very elegant (creating a temporary mutable instance seems to be an overhead). 
So now I'm looking for better implementations depending on the use case.

What would be the best implementations for these cases:

1. focus on performance
2. focus on memory consumption
3. focus on code brevity.

Comment: This really is a case of premature optimization - use `[NSMutableArray copy]` to return an immutable collection. Unless you've profiled your application and found this method to be a huge bottleneck, focus on correctness and safety rather than trying to optimize unnecessarily. What is contained in foos? Can you return an array literal containing all of the myObjects?

Comment: Maybe you are suggesting a 4. case 'focus on correctness and safety'? The number of objects is determined at runtime, so I don't see how I could return an array literal.

Comment: I'm suggesting a 1. this is premature optimization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a subclass of [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray), so this will work just fine:

```
return _temporaryArray;
```

(I would avoid the `_` prefix, however, as that is commonly used to signify instance variables, not `auto` variables).

This seems to fit your criteria:

1. focus on performance: **no need to make a copy**.
2. focus on memory consumption: **no need to make a copy**.
3. focus on code brevity: **no need to make a copy**.

Note, however, the caller could, in theory, cast your `NSArray` back to an `NSMutableArray` and start modifying the object, however there is only so much you should worry about.

Comment: They could also create a mutable copy and add objects to that, either way the OPs method/object doesn't the returned array so it's irrelevant :) +1 as this way avoids the overhead of creating a second array.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor point:

```
NSMutableArray *temporaryArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[foos count]];
```

Although the runtime will only take the capacity as an advisory number, rather than creating one exactly that size.